# migrating Java EE application from jboss to websphere6.1 app server

Tags: websphere-6.1

I have a task of making a existing JBoss webapp working in Websphere6.1.

This web application runs in JBoss currently. There are other applications (swing app, standalone apps like calculator etc) that are mixed up in the deploy folder of JBoss. I could figure out the ear that is needed for my webapp. There is a EJB jar which is not part of the ear that my webapp needs.

How can I generate the required deployment files for Websphere easily?

1. copied the ABC-ejb.jar (calculator like app) and pasted it on D:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv02\config\cells\WAS61Node01Cell\applications\ABC-ejb.jar
2. Opened WAS admin console, Applications-->Install new application.
3. Kept mostly the defaults. At the end I got errors.

error: Invalid class file format in D:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv02\wstemp\wstemp\app_1377ff3f693\dpl\7c4f55f9\ABC-ejb\ImportedClasses\com\xyz\xyz\example\ejb2\ABCRemote.class. The major.minor version '51.0' is too recent for this tool to understand.

error: Class com.xyz.xyz.example.ejb2.ABCRemote not found in class com.xyz.xyz.example.ejb2.EJSRemoteStatelessLisaCalculator_d78ab53c.

error: Invalid class file format in D:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv02\wstemp\wstemp\app_1377ff3f693\dpl\7c4f55f9\ABC-ejb\ImportedClasses\com\xyz\xyz\example\ejb2\ABCHome.class. The major.minor version '51.0' is too recent for this tool to understand.

error: Class com.xyz.xyz.example.ejb2.ABCHome not found in class com.xyz.xyz.example.ejb2.EJSRemoteStatelessABCHome_d78ab53c.

4 errors

I have Eclipse Indigo installed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This error:

> The major.minor version '51.0' is too recent for this tool to
>   understand.

...means that the class has been compiled using [Java 7](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file#General_layout) (major version number 51), but WebSphere Application Server 6.1 only supports Java 5.  You'll need to recompile the classes in order to deploy on that version.